# I Think my code is perfect but the output is not proper

Tags: c++, oop

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Personal_Record {

    public:
        Personal_Record();
        Personal_Record(string nam, string dob, string addr, int mobNum, string ema, string hob);
        void Get_PersonalRecord();
        void Display_PersonalRecord();

    protected:
        string name;
        string dateOfBirth;
        string address;
        int mobileNumber;
        string emailId;
        string hobby;

};

Personal_Record::Personal_Record() 
{
    name = "";
    dateOfBirth = "";
    address = "";
    hobby = "";
}

Personal_Record::Personal_Record(string nam, string dob, string addr, int mobNum, string ema, string hob)
{
    name = nam;
    dateOfBirth = dob;
    address = addr;
    mobileNumber = mobNum;
    emailId = ema;
    hobby = hob;
}


void Personal_Record::Get_PersonalRecord()
{
    cout << endl << "Enter the name of the person: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << endl << "Enter the date of birth: ";
    cin >> dateOfBirth;
    cout << endl << "Enter the address: ";
    cin >> address;
    cout << endl << "Enter the mobile number: ";
    cin >> mobileNumber;
    cout << endl << "Enter the e-mail id: ";
    cin >> emailId;
    cout << endl << "Enter any hobby the person has: ";
    cin >> hobby;
}

void Personal_Record::Display_PersonalRecord()
{
    cout << "Personal Record:" << endl << endl;
    cout << "1.Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "2.Date Of Birth: " << dateOfBirth << endl;
    cout << "3.Address: " << address << endl;
    cout << "4.Mobile Number: " << mobileNumber << endl;
    cout << "5.E-mail Id: " << emailId << endl;
    cout << "6.Hobby" << hobby << endl; 
}

class Professional_Record {

    public:
        Professional_Record();
        Professional_Record(string nameOfCom, string pos, int xp);
        void Get_Professional_Record();
        void Display_Professional_Record();

    protected:
        string nameOfCompany;
        string position;
        int experienceInYears;

};

Professional_Record::Professional_Record()
{
    nameOfCompany = "";
    position = "";
    experienceInYears = 0;
}

Professional_Record::Professional_Record(string nameOfCom, string pos, int xp)
{
    nameOfCompany = nameOfCom;
    position = pos;
    experienceInYears = xp;
}

void Professional_Record::Get_Professional_Record()
{
    cout << endl << "Enter name of the company: ";
    cin >> nameOfCompany;
    cout << endl << "Enter position in this company: ";
    cin >> position;
    cout << endl << "Enter number of years of experience: ";
    cin >> experienceInYears;
}


void Professional_Record::Display_Professional_Record()
{
    cout << "Professional Record: " << endl << endl;
    cout << "Name of the Company: " << nameOfCompany << endl;
    cout << "Position in this company: " << position << endl;
    cout << "Number of years of experience: " << experienceInYears << endl; 
}

class Academic_Record {

    public:
        Academic_Record();
        Academic_Record(string nameOfCou, string nameOfCol, int passOut, float percent, string special);
        void Get_Academic_Record();
        void Display_Academic_Record();

    protected:
        string nameOfCourse;
        string nameOfCollege;
        int passOutYear;
        float percentage;
        string specialization;

};

Academic_Record::Academic_Record()
{
    nameOfCourse = "";
    nameOfCollege = "";
    passOutYear = 0;
    percentage = 0.0;
    specialization = "";
}

Academic_Record::Academic_Record(string nameOfCou, string nameOfCol, int passOut, float percent, string special)
{
    nameOfCourse = nameOfCou;
    nameOfCollege = nameOfCol;
    passOutYear = passOut;
    percentage = percent;
    specialization = special;
}

void Academic_Record::Get_Academic_Record()
{
    cout << endl << "Enter the name of the course: ";
    cin >> nameOfCourse;
    cout << endl << "Enter the name of the college: ";
    cin >> nameOfCollege;
    cout << endl << "Enter year of passout: ";
    cin >> passOutYear;
    cout << endl << "Enter the percentage: ";
    cin >> percentage;
    cout << endl << "Enter the subject the person has specialized in: ";
    cin >> specialization;
}

void Academic_Record::Display_Academic_Record()
{
    cout << endl << "Academic Details:" << endl;
    cout << "Name of the Course: " << nameOfCourse << endl;
    cout << "Name of the College: " <<  nameOfCollege << endl;
    cout << "Year of passout: " <<  passOutYear << endl;
    cout << "Percentage acquired: " << percentage << endl;
    cout << "The person has specialized in: " << specialization << endl;
}

class Bio_Data : public Personal_Record, public Professional_Record, public Academic_Record {

    public:
        void Display_BioData();

};

void Bio_Data::Display_BioData()
{
    Display_PersonalRecord();
    Display_Professional_Record();
    Display_Academic_Record();
}

int main()
{
    Bio_Data bd;
    cout << "Enter Personal Information: " << endl << endl;
    bd.Get_PersonalRecord();
    cout << "Enter Professional Information: " << endl << endl;
    bd.Get_Professional_Record();
    cout << "Enter Academic Information: " << endl << endl;
    bd.Get_Academic_Record();
    bd.Display_BioData();
    return 0;
}
```

Output of the following code:
Enter Personal Information:

Enter the name of the person: Suraj

Enter the date of birth: 02/04/1996

Enter the address: Varnam,A/38,Pune

Enter the mobile number: 8552004340

Enter the e-mail id: 
Enter any hobby the person has: Enter Professional Information:

Enter name of the company: 
Enter position in this company: 
Enter number of years of experience: Enter Academic Information:

Enter the name of the course: 
Enter the name of the college: 
Enter year of passout: 
Enter the percentage: 
Enter the subject the person has specialized in: Personal Record:

1.Name: Suraj
2.Date Of Birth: 02/04/1996
3.Address: Varnam,A/38,Pune
4.Mobile Number: 2147483647
5.E-mail Id: 
6.Hobby
Professional Record:

Name of the Company: 
Position in this company: 
Number of years of experience: 0

Academic Details:
Name of the Course: 
Name of the College: 
Year of passout: 0
Percentage acquired: 0
The person has specialized in:

The problem here is that after taking the mobile number it doesn't give me a prompt for email id or taking input for any other fields.It just gives me the output.And even in the output the mobile no. is turned into some garbage value not the original no. I entered.I really don't know whats going on.Can someone help me!

I have run the code on ubuntu and c++ shell online and they both seem to give me same results.

I don't know what this problem is called so don't get angry at me for asking this question!

Comment: This not minimal code in any way.

Comment: I recommend that you use multiple classes. Each one per information type. Later, you can learn about [Friendship and inheritance](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/). That will give you a cleaner code. My $0.02

Comment: Okay so you are asking me to not use multiple inheritance but just instantiate the 3 classes right?Joel

Comment: Actual is the other way around: use multiple inheritance derivaded from a base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing the mobile number as an int, which has a max size of 32767 http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/

8552004340 is too big!

Better to store it as a string.

Comment: Agree with the int thing.

Comment: thank you so much ravenspoint!.I just forgot about the sizes.

Comment: Also phone numbers can have leading zeros, and also the + notation for country codes.

Comment: I know it is nit picking but an `int` has to have a max at least as large as 32767.  It could be much larger like on most 32-bit and 64-bit systems.

Comment: @NathanOliver It is important not to have a design that breaks if the code is built on a different platform.  An int in C is guaranteed to hold 32767 and notjhing more.and